# How to read a file with variables and data in three columns in R

Tags: r

Hello I need to know how to read a csv file in the format that many variables are in the first column, their date are in the second column and their data are in the third column

```
VARIABLES      DATE       DATA
V1           1/03/2012    1000  
V1           1/04/2012    1500
..
V1           1/12/2012    2600
V2           1/03/2012    900
V2           1/04/2012    1200
...
V2           1/12/2012    1000
V3           1/03/2012    200
....
```

How can I extract each variable Vi in correspondence with its data and date(for example in an array??)

Comment: Hello Jack I refer to the commands read.table or read.csv..if there is an alternative to extract the data in the format i especify

Comment: @isidromorales: Also some code that shows what you have tried would be useful.

Comment: the final result should be for example a data frame or matrix, i don't know exactly what is the structure it should be: for i=1:n {(n number of variables) v(i,1)=V1 v(i,2)=date and v(i,3)=data}

Comment: @isidromorales: Could you update your question, please? Scanning comments for details is cumbersome.

Comment: you are ok, sorry for the confusion My problem mainly is reshaping the data.to format the data from the csv file...if i have V1 date1 data1.....v1 date2 data2....Vn date2 datan in columns format...how can i process the variables individually..perhaps a loop?(there are 10000  variables..with data..there are a total of 3000000 of records aprox

Comment: @isidromorales: You can edit your question to add any additional detail you want. If the additional detail falls out of scope of the original question, better open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The example data is not in the `csv` format. You could use `read.table` to read the file:

```
dat <- read.table(text="VARIABLES      DATE       DATA
V1           1/03/2012    1000  
V1           1/04/2012    1500

V1           1/12/2012    2600
V2           1/03/2012    900
V2           1/04/2012    1200

V2           1/12/2012    1000
V3           1/03/2012    200", header = TRUE)
```

This will create a data frame. You could create a list of smaller data frames (one for each value in `VARIABLES`) with the split function:

```
split(dat, dat$VARIABLES)
```

The result:

```
$V1
  VARIABLES      DATE DATA
1        V1 1/03/2012 1000
2        V1 1/04/2012 1500
3        V1 1/12/2012 2600

$V2
  VARIABLES      DATE DATA
4        V2 1/03/2012  900
5        V2 1/04/2012 1200
6        V2 1/12/2012 1000

$V3
  VARIABLES      DATE DATA
7        V3 1/03/2012  200
```

Comment: @isidromorales: In that case, please upvote and/or accept.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, building upon Sven's answer, is to use the `reshape` package to, well, reshape the data:

```
> library(reshape)
> dat.m <- melt(dat, id.vars=c('VARIABLES', 'DATE'))
> head(dat.m)
  VARIABLES      DATE variable value
1        V1 1/03/2012     DATA  1000
2        V1 1/04/2012     DATA  1500
3        V1 1/12/2012     DATA  2600
4        V2 1/03/2012     DATA   900
5        V2 1/04/2012     DATA  1200
6        V2 1/12/2012     DATA  1000
> dat.c <- as.data.frame(cast(dat.m, VARIABLES~DATE+.))
> head(dat.c)
  VARIABLES 1/03/2012 1/04/2012 1/12/2012
1        V1      1000      1500      2600
2        V2       900      1200      1000
3        V3       200        NA        NA
```

The basic idea is this: `melt` distinguishes between `id.vars` (identificator columns) and `measure.vars` (what you actually measure) and reformats any data frame with given ID and measure columns into a default format (with `variable` and `value` columns). After that, `cast` allows you to specify how you would like your data to look like. I had a hard time figuring out the correct syntax for `cast` until I have found a basic rule: In the formula argument, anything on the left side of the `~` is aligned in rows, anything on the right side is aligned in columns.

See also this gist: https://gist.github.com/4603945